# Add results from MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, count

Not quite sure how descriptive that title was but this is what I want to do.  I scripted a URL shortener today and it's working fine, I just want to add some stats on the bottom of it saying how many links there are and how many clicks there are.  Now everytime a user clicks one of the links it +1 the column in the database then it redirects the user.  I want to query that and add all of those numbers together from each row.  I attempted a while loop which im not surprised didn't work:

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_count)){
    $clicks = $rows['clicks'];
    $clicks = $clicks+$clicks;
}
```

If you don't understand please ask and if you do understand it means alot for any response!

Comment: why not query the database for the number of clicks? `select sum(clicks) from the_table`

Comment: You keep running over `$clicks` how about `$clicks += $rows['clicks'];`?

Comment: Oh I got it! here is what I did: `$get_clicks = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(clicks) AS total_clicks FROM urls");`  Then get it with mysql_fetch_assoc, thanks for putting me in the right direction!

Comment: @NardCake: Every time you're about to iterate and reduce/filter your tuples somehow, it's usually something that could be done in the database. It will be cleaner and more efficient that way.